# nextcord.py bot has no attribute slash_command

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

This used to work before but now it has started displaying this error

```
@bot.slash_command(name="ping", description="Shows the ping", guild_ids=[988865437272010762])
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'slash_command'
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use these lines of code

```py
tree = bot.tree
@tree.command(name="ping", description="Shows the ping", guild_ids=[988865437272010762])
```

Of course, no need to redefine `tree` for each command.

Comment: I don't think this answer is related to nextcord. It appears to be discord.py

Comment: Oh! True! But why not use directly the discord API? @pinkguy does it help you or should I remove my answer?